# Issue reading property value into oozie workflow

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie

There is oozie workflow with 3 actions
1)fact_load
2)load_data
3)aggr_data

In the second action('load_data'), I get the job_id of first action('fact_load') by using
${wf:actionExternalId('fact_load')} which returns job_1416624124931_10774

```
<action name="load_data">
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<exec>/user/a123/test.sh
</exec>
<argument>${wf:id()}</argument>
<argument>${dbname}</argument>
<argument>${wf:actionExternalId('fact_load')}</argument>
<file>/user/a123/test.sh#test.sh
</file>
</shell>
<ok to="aggr_data" />
<error to="kill" />
</action>
```

If I try to get job_id by passing the action name from properties file, it throws EL_ERROR for the below syntax, there are no issues while reading other properties except for this property.

${wf:actionExternalId($action2)}

How to handle the scenario?

### job.properties

action2=fact_load

Comment: The `wf:actionExternalId()` function is a part of Oozie's expression language syntax, and cannot use values defined in the properties file. This is why passing `'fact_load'` directly is successful but the latter fails. Why do you need the job id for your second action?

Comment: My requirement is to capture all the 3 job id's for a given job within the oozie workflow. Is there any other way apart from wf:actionExternalId() or any command line syntax?

Comment: I think in this case your best bet would be to explicitly call external id for each of the three actions.